# What is the compatibility between Linux Window Managers and Android?

Tags: x11, android, wayland

I'm particularly interested in the compatibility between **Wayland** and **Android** (although I'm also curious about **X** and **Android**).

For example: does a Wayland window manager work on Android?  Conversely, can you get Android apps to work on Wayland (or X) window manager?

And overall, is there a single window manager on Android that is near universally used, or are there a multitude of them (just like on linux, where there is a multitude of window managers out there used across the various distros)?

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct compatibility between Linux and Android applications at all. They are totally different. You can run Android application on Linux in an emulator that emulates full Android environment. You can run full Linux emulation or a library-level emulation of Linux on Android.